# Is date conversion not implemented when reading CSV using pyarrow?

Tags: csv, pyarrow

I want to use `pyarrow 0.14.1` in Python 3.6 to read a CSV file which has a column called Date where the date values are in `YYYY-MM-DD` format (e.g. 2018-11-17).

I want to convert the date values to date32() format using `ConvertOptions.columntypes` as shown in the code below.

However, I get an `ArrowNotImplementedError`.

Does this mean that this feature is not yet implemented?

I searched the pyarrow docs and the pyarrow issues forum on GitHub as well as searching generally on the web but the most similar issue I could find is https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/3223 which is not the same.

```py
import pyarrow as pa
from pyarrow import csv

file_path = '/home/wajadoogle/csvWithDateInYYY-MM-DDFormat.csv'

opts = csv.ConvertOptions()
opts.column_types = {'Date': pa.date32()}

table = csv.read_csv(file_path, convert_options=opts)
```

I get the following error.

```
File "/home/wajadogle/TestPyarrow.py", line 9, in <module>
    table = csv.read_csv(file_path, convert_options=opts)
File "pyarrow/_csv.pyx", line 450, in pyarrow._csv.read_csv
File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 93, in pyarrow.lib.check_status

pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: CSV conversion to date32[day] is not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question on the pyarrow issues forum on GitHub https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/5209 and there was already an open issue on the apache site.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-3739

The pyarrow community are looking for help to implement this feature.

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of `pyarrow` the conversion works automatically "out of the box".

However, if you want to use `ConvertOptions.columntypes` as requested in this question:

```
column_types = { 'Date': pa.date32() }
convert_options = pa.csv.ConvertOptions(column_types=column_types)
table = pa.csv.read_csv(CSV_FILENAME, convert_options=convert_options)
```